# Where in AWS is the Elastic Beanstalk Subdomain CNAME Record, and How to Add SSL to it?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-elb

[Your Elastic Beanstalk environment's Domain name](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customdomains.html) says:

> To route users to your environment, Elastic Beanstalk registers a
> CNAME record that points to your environment's load balancer. You can
> see URL of your environment's application with the current value of
> the CNAME in the environment overview page of the Elastic Beanstalk
> console.

**My simple questions are:**

1. where is this CNAME record located in AWS?
2. is it possible to make this subdomain SSL (redirect http to https)?

**Why would I want to do this?**

My application works fine, but Elastic Beanstalk says my health is "Severe" (red exclamation) when the only thing wrong is that I intentionally made my real domain (the non-Elastic Beanstalk subdomain) I have in Route 53 redirect to https (443) by [modifying the load balancer](https://github.com/awsdocs/elastic-beanstalk-samples/blob/main/configuration-files/aws-provided/resource-configuration/alb-http-to-https-redirection-full.config). Now this Elastic Beanstalk subdomain also routes to https when it's not setup, which is what causes the health error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> where is this CNAME record located in AWS?

It is AWS-owned domain, so AWS holds it in its systems.

> is it possible to make this subdomain SSL (redirect http to https)?

No, its not, because it belongs to AWS, not you. For proper HTTPS, you need **your own domain** that you can control. If you have such a domain, you can free SSL certificate for it from AWS ACM.

Comment: Once someone sets up http to https in an Elastic Beanstalk environment, the "Health" will always show "Severe" from that point on? Is there an exception that can be given to this subdomain at the load balancer? Or can a health check be modified so it doesn't show "Severe" in the interface?

Comment: @Jarad HTTPs should only be for your load balancer. Between load balancer and your instances there should be HTTP.

Comment: [modifying the load balancer](https://github.com/awsdocs/elastic-beanstalk-samples/blob/main/configuration-files/aws-provided/resource-configuration/alb-http-to-https-redirection-full.config) sets two rules on the load balancer: 1) redirect http (80) to https (443) and 2) forward to target group (awseb-AWSEB-...X259) which also defines my SSL certificate for my domain from ACM. Since EB subdomain goes to port 80, I think this is why it redirects. But this creates "Severe" warning as a result.

Comment: @Jarad Your question does not provide any details about your setup, eb logs, error messages. Its difficult to speculate.